# Selenium test automation, driver.get(url) happens before website starts up

Tags: python, selenium

I am building a test automation of a website docker image using Selenium python. In the configuration phase,

`driver.get(myurl)` could return connection refused error because the web page is not up yet.

I thought implicitly_wait() can solve this. So I put

```
driver.implicitly_wait(90)
driver.get(myurl)
```

But exception still thrown immediately.

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any suggestion? Should I use explicit wait instead?

My current hack is to create a wait function that check until `driver.get()` no longer raise an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

import config
from utils import SureThing, json_load

def wait_untill_loaded(driver, url, seconds=60):
    """Wait until driver can connect to url"""
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start <= seconds:
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            if driver.title:
                return driver
        except:
            pass
    raise WebDriverException("net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED")

driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=driver_options)
driver = wait_untill_loaded(driver, myweblocalurl)
```

Comment: Could you provide bit more information (webdriver, url, ... ) thanks

Comment: Just in case your started your localhost you provided? That causes the error in one of my tests. Do you also get an error  if your requesting another url (google, ...)?

Comment: @HedgeHog, I added the current hack, myweblocalurl is just some localhost with port.

Comment: ... I am afraid you misunderstand. Of course google will be fine because it is already is an up and running website. I am referring to a local server that takes a few seconds to start, which is started from docker-compose. If python runtime reaches driver.get() before the webpage is served it will raise connection error.